# html page max-width by knowing the size of inside divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, fluid-layout

This is my HTML code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="menu-vertical">menu-vertical</div>
    <div class="mainContent">mainContent</div>
</div>​
```

This is my CSS

```
.container {
    border: 3px solid #666;
    overflow: hidden
}
.menu-vertical {
    width: 230px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #f0f
}
.mainContent {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #00f
}​
```

Now i want to make few `div` inside `mainContent` of fixed size lets say `150px` however if the `mainContent` width became, lets say `650px` then i'll be having 4 `div` in a row then again 4 in a row. So 4 `div` means it will be of `600px`, hence i'll be having an extra `50px` of space.

Now finally what exactly i want to do is to detect this empty space and making the `mainContent` `max-width` to 600px`. Any trick which can do this. Javascript or something.

Comment: so you want the main div to shrink to 600. then what happens next? does the container shrink? does the menu increase in width?

Comment: yes i want the div to shrink.

Comment: try using `min-width:600` instead of `width:650`

Comment: @Joseph, you are unable to understand my css, i would not be able to know the width of `mainContent` as it would be auto generated. So how would i be able to detect it in live mode??

Comment: you didn't mention it was "auto"

Comment: @Joseph yes if it could be done using jquery, i would not be having any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10011466/1182021

Here is the link for the answer... after waiting for long i come up to this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution using jquery:

```
$(function(){
   var outerdiv = $('.mainContent');
   var innerdivs = $('.mainContent > div'); 
   var sum =0;

    innerdivs.each(function(index){
        sum += $(this).width();    //calculate and add the widths of every div
    });   

    //outerdiv.width(sum);        //set new width for .maincontent

    outerdiv.css("max-width", sum);   //you can also set max-width like this.
});
```

You can check out the jsfiddle for this here: http://jsfiddle.net/jqYK6/

Regards,
Saurabh

Comment: check this out: i have modified it a bit... an issue if you can fix

http://jsfiddle.net/jqYK6/2/

Comment: i'll try to do that, this will require setting a maximum allowed width for `maincontent`.